# Algorithm that given a word returns the minimum amount of letters needed to remove from it to become an anagram of a palindrome

Tags: algorithm, palindrome, anagram

I need a non-brute force algorithm for determining the minimum amount of letters you need to remove from a word for it to become an anagram of a palindrome.

For instance: `abba` -> 0, `abbac` -> 0, `aabbfghj` -> 3, `a` -> 0, `abcdefghij` -> 9.

Brute force algo can look like this:

```
1. Send word to method (2.) with counter 0
2. Check if any anagrams of word is palindrome, if yes return counter, if no go to 3.
3. Remove head of word, send to method (2.) with counter++
```

The brute force method is O(n*n!) complexity I believe (since for each word, there are n! anagrams, and n letters to remove). This will take way too long for strings n=1000 for example. So I need a better algorithm but am unsure of what I can check on the string to determine the amount of letters needed to remove.

Since all palindromes of n>1 have a pair/letter multiple somewhere (`aba` has pair `aa`, `abcba` pair `aa` and `bb`, `aaab` has `aaa`) I thought about removing all multiples of a letter then returning the length of the new word-1, or just the length if it's 0. This works for a lot of words, but it still fails for some. For example:

```
"aabbfghj" (remove pairs) -> "fghj" (length >0) -> return length-1 = 3 correct
"aabbcc" -> "" (!length >0) -> return length = 0 correct
"aaabb" -> "" -> 0 correct
"aaabbb" -> "" -> 0 correct
"aaabbbccdef" -> "def" -> 2 correct
"aaaaab" -> "b" -> 0 correct
"aabbc" -> "c" -> 0 correct
"aaabbc" -> "c" -> 0 incorrect (should be 1)
```

Am I missing something super simple here? How can I construct an algorithm that will return the minimum amount of letters you need to remove from a word to get an angram of a palindrome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I missing something super simple here?

Yes you are :-)
Being an anagram of a palindrome can be characterized as follows:
a word `w` is an anagram of a palindrome if and only if, there exists at most one character `c` such that the number of  occurences of `c` in `w` is odd (I let you see why that is true, test on simple cases).

So, given a word `w`, count for each character of `w`, the number of times it appears. Then count how many characters appear an odd number of times in `w` (let's call this `k`). The number of letters to remove so `w` can be the anagram of a palindrome is `0` if `k=0` or if `k=1`. Otherwise it is `k-1`.